# List generation speed change at ~800 iterations

Tags: list-manipulation, timing

I recently have been developing a project for my students to explore some functionality of the Wolfram Language and have requested that they investigate the timing for several different methods of list generation. Here are the techniques i've asked them to explore:

```
p1 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[First[Table[Prime[n], {n, 1, k}] // AbsoluteTiming], {k, 1, 200000, 1000}], 
    PlotStyle -> Black];
p2 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[First[Prime[Range[k]] // AbsoluteTiming], {k, 1, 200000, 1000}], 
    PlotStyle -> Red];
p3 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[First[Reap[Do[Sow[Prime[n]], {n, k}]] // AbsoluteTiming], {k, 1, 200000, 1000}], 
    PlotStyle -> Green];
p4 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[
      First[Reap[For[n = 1, n <= k, n++, Sow[Prime[n]]]] // AbsoluteTiming], 
      {k, 1, 200000, 1000}], 
    PlotStyle -> Blue];
p5 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[First[Array[Prime[#] &, k] // AbsoluteTiming], {k, 1, 200000,1000}], 
    PlotStyle -> Orange];

Show[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]
```

The result is the following graph:

[image: Plot of timing as a function of iterations]

Is there something special happening around $n=80000$? Looks like the rate of change of cost for creating a list of prime numbers is abruptly changing near this value.

Comment: Using `Prime` as test is somewhat atypical. It would provide _much_ more insight using a function that is also vectorized such as `f = Sin[N[#]] &;`. I guess that `Prime` shifts from a very cheap algorithm for small primes (maybe a lookup table) to a more general, but also more expensive algorithm. The fact that the performance curves look continuous tells me that this switching is either well-balanced or that simply an additional effort has to be made for primes after the 80k-th one. Btw., `Array[Prime, k]` will speed up `p5` a little.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I replaced `Prime` with `Sin` and no change in slope is visible.

Comment: @mikado Right. That was my point. `Prime` does not show how Mathematica works in general. I am not sure whether _any_ real computations are done at all with `Prime` in this range of numbers; maybe only two different file formats for the storage of primes are used: one with low compression for the first 80000 primes and one with higher compression (and thus slower access) for the next 120000 primes.

Comment: Can this be the point where compilation no longer works because the numbers involved become too large to be represent by machine integers?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I don't think so: Mathematica's integers are 64 bit long. ``N[Developer`$MaxMachineInteger/Prime[80000]]`` returns almost `10^13`. So the machine integer border is far, far away.

Comment: Is there a way to examine the algorithm used by Prime[] so that one could actually get to the bottom of this?

Comment: After some searching around on the topic of underlying algorithms in Mathematica, it seems unlikely that the end user has this type of information available. I think this might spark some interesting conjectures in class. I'll leave Prime[] in.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Regarding this statement

> Looks like the rate of change of cost for creating a list is abruptly changing near this value.

I have a different opinion. We can use `RepeatedTiming` to get a somewhat consistent measurement and check the runtime for one single `Prime` call taking the list creation out of the game

```
data1 = Table[{i, First[RepeatedTiming[Prime[i]]]}, {i, 1, 100000, 
    100}];
ListLinePlot[data1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we see the same jump, and I believe it is a switch from one algorithm to the next in calculating the primes. On closer inspection, you will find that the position of the jump appears to be precisely at n=78499. Why? I guess the reason is that we reached one million:

```
Prime[78498]
Prime[78499]
(* 999983 *)
(* 1000003 *)
```

In the documentation we find

> Prime and PrimePi use sparse caching and sieving. For large n, the Lagarias–Miller–Odlyzko algorithm for PrimePi is used, based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give Prime.

So let's assume for n<78499 Mathematica uses caching. Then getting a result, mostly depends on how fast the lookup is. Of course, you need to take into account the real smart users, who, when using `Prime[n]` definitely will request `Prime[n+1]` (or 2,3,...).

Let us make an experiment. Instead of using `RepeatedTiming`, we will simply access `dn` primes and measure the time. So we will *touch* each prime but we measure in chunks:

```
With[{dn = 100},
  dataDoForward = 
   Table[{i, First[AbsoluteTiming[Do[Prime[j], {j, i, i + dn}]]]}, {i,
      1, 150000, dn}]
];
ListLinePlot[dataDoForward, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No surprise here. The same jump. However, what happens if we access the primes in the inner `Do` in reverse order?

```
With[{dn = 100},
  dataDoReverse = 
   Table[{i, 
     First[AbsoluteTiming[Do[Prime[j], {j, i + dn, i, -1}]]]}, {i, 1, 
     150000, dn}]
  ];
ListLinePlot[dataDoReverse, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems the Wolfram Developers are counting on that we are somewhat reasonable people that don't do these stunts. Please pay particular attention to the order of the difference in time. For 100 primes around n=75000 we need under 0.1 microseconds, while the reverse access is almost 1000x slower.

So my conclusion without official information is that primes under 1 million are heavily cached and accessing them loads some larger primes so that the next access is faster. For lager primes, an algorithm is used that really *calculates* the result. This seems stable in timing, no matter if you access chunks of primes forward or backwards

```
ListLinePlot[{dataDoForward, dataDoReverse}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.0005}},
 PlotLegends -> {"Forward Access", "Backward Access"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I cannot explain, why the forward access method is a bit slower at the beginning for primes larger 1 million, but it is possible that some caches need to be cleared. This however is a topic for someone who actually knows what Wolfram is doing under the hood.

Comment: I see the cost of computing Prime is the suspect. I have edited this into the last sentence.